# external php form results

Tags: php, html

I have created dynamic pricing forms within a e-commerce site using javascript and it works fine. However I would prefer my more complex pricing computations to be in a PHP file external to the HTML form.
The calculations are fairly complex and I have got them all working using PHP however I am new to PHP and for the life of me cant figure out how to get the result of the calculations to be returned to the html form. The user can then "Add to Cart"

Here are very simple examples to try and explain

HTML form

```
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>demoform</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="myform.php">
<label>Width<input type="text" name="width" id="width" size="6"></label><p>
<label>Length<input type="text" name="length" id="length" size="6" ></label><p>
<label>Price $</label> <input id="Price" readOnly size=6 name=Price><p>
<label for=otherprice></label><input id="otherprice" readOnly size=6  type=hidden 
name=otherprice><p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Get Price" ><p>
<input id="addtocart" title="Add to Cart" onclick="return validate(this.form)" value="Add to Cart" type="submit" ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

PHP File

```
<?php

$width=$_POST['width'];
$length=$_POST['length'];
$Area = $width*$length;
$total = $Area * .01;
$price = round($total * 100) / 100;
$otherprice = round($price * 1.2 * 100)/100 ;

?>

<?php echo "$price"?><br/>
<?php echo "$otherprice"?>
```

---

Instead of a new page opening is it possible
for $price to be input into the HTML price field
and for $otherprice to be input into the HTML otherprice (hidden) field within the demoform.html page

John

Comment: If i haven't misunderstood you, you can use ajax to communicate with an external php file. Just search for jquery ajax on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PHP script:**

```
<?php
$width =$_GET['width'];
$length = $_GET['length'];
$area = $width * $length;
$total = $area * .01;
$price = round($total * 100) / 100;
$otherprice = round($price * 1.2 * 100) / 100;

echo json_encode(array($price, $otherprice));
?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function Ajax() {
    this.instance = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    this.request = function(url, callback) {
        this.instance.open('GET', url, true);
        this.instance.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                callback(this.responseText);
            }
        }
        this.instance.send(null);
    }
}
function validate(form) {
    (new Ajax).request('prices.php?width=' + form.width.value + '&length=' + form.length.value, function(respons) {
        var prices = eval(respons);
        form.price.value = prices[0];
        form.otherprice.value = prices[1];
    });
}
```

The `Ajax` class is something that I created. You are free to use it or not. You can also do it without the class. I usually do it this way because it's easy to make multiple `XHR` objects.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="myform.php">
    <p>
        <label>Width <input type="text" name="width" size="6" /></label><br />
        <label>Length <input type="text" name="length" size="6" ></label><br />
        <label>Price <input type="text" name="price" readonly="readonly" size="6" /></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="otherprice" readonly="readonly" size="6" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Get Price" onclick="validate(this.form)" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Also please clean up your HTML. :)

Comment: Hi Midas - Thanks for the quick reply - havent been able to get it working though. AJAX is brand new to me - do I place code in html file as i would javascript

Comment: Place the JS in the HTML file of your form. And the PHP code should be in 'prices.php', as requested by AJAX.

Comment: thanks again - my bad - had named it price.php - am getting field populated however it is with zero - calcs seem to have gone amiss

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want leading zeros on your numbers or something?

Comment: HI Midas - if I was using 3 variables would - function validate(form) {
    (new Ajax).request('prices.php?width=' + form.width.value + '&length=' + form.length.value, function(respons become                                                               (new Ajax).request('prices.php?AB=' + form.AB.value + '&BC=' + form.BC.value + '&CA=' + form.CA.value, function(respons

Comment: if i am calculating the area of a triangle and I am using - $Area = pow(($AB+$BC+$CA)/2*(($AB+$BC+$CA)/2-$AB) * (($AB+$BC+$CA)/2-$BC) * (($AB+$BC+$CA)/2-$CA),0.5); then i gather that becomes a whole different ball game

Comment: Thanks again Midas - you have pointed me in the right direction - AJAX 101 for me!